# Making my drop down menu collapse when an anchor link is clicked on small devices using javascript

Tags: javascript, responsive

so i am trying to make my responsive drop down menu that shows up when smaller screens are active collapse when an anchor link is selected from the dropdown menu.

i've looked all over the internet for solutions, but i'm lost.  Ive seen a few solutions, but i don't know how to fit them into my specific code...can someone maybe help me figure this out...

the specific page i am referring to is http://www.valentinosgourmet.com/menu.html

here is the script code currently.. there are 2 because i have the main navigation navbar and then a second one with all the menu stuff

> // Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon

```
    function myFunctionGetMainNav() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }

</script>

<script>
// Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to menunav when the user clicks on the icon

    function myFunctionGetMenuNav() {
        var x = document.getElementById("menuNavbar");
        if (x.className === "menunav") {
            x.className += " responsiveMenu";
        } else {
            x.className = "menunav";
        }
    }

</script>
```

any help in the right direction would be much appreciated!

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

so i was able to figure it out finally... (i have a new problem though now. the offset is not working correctly) here is the code i needed though to make the menu collapse when clicking an anchor link...

```
// JavaScript Document


//menu navigation bar
$(document).ready(function(){

// --- Mobile Menu -------------------------
$("#menu-icon, .menunav a").click(function(){
  if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
    $("#main-navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#menu-icon i").toggleClass("icon-close");
  }
});



// --- Smooth Scroll -----------------------

  $('a[href*="#"]')
.not('[href="#"]')
.not('[href="#0"]')
.click(function(event) {
  if (
  location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
  &&
  location.hostname == this.hostname
  ) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
     if (target.length) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
        }, 1000, function() {
            var $target = $(target);
         $target.focus();
         if ($target.is(":focus")) {
           return false;
        } else {
        $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
        $target.focus();
        };
      });
      }
     }
   });
 }); // --- End document ---------------------------------------------------------
```

hope this helps someone. if anyone know why the offset isn't staying offset let me know please..it starts to offset, but then when it gets to the offset it jumps back up to the top (under the header) :(